# React useRef with Typescript: Property 'playbackRate' does not exist on type 'HTMLAudioElement'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to typescript, seeing this odd declaration: `Property 'playbackRate' does not exist on type 'HTMLAudioElement'.ts(2339)`

To reproduce (simplified for brevity here):

```
const audioElement = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>()
audioElement!.current!.playbackRate = 1;

<audio ref={audioElement} />
```

MDN shows `playbackRate` as a property of `HTMLMediaElement`, but that's apparently not a typescript interface option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playbackRate

I also can't find a list of interfaces that are available. Ie. why is `HTMLAudioElement` available but `HTMLMediaElement` is not? I'm sure it must be documented somewhere, I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in TS 4.1.2, the code in the question works for me. `(property) HTMLMediaElement.playbackRate: number` You may have oversimplified? Or the version difference is the cause

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think `.current` is the difference - `.current` must be used to reference the element.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was missing the appropriate compiler options in my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
```